# Updating list item permissions from 2013 SPD Workflow on SharePoint Online

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, designer-workflow, sharepoint-designer

I have a list with some simple workflow which includes setting a list item to read only once it reaches a certain status.
To achieve this I have extended the existing SPD 2013 list workflow by adding a SPD 2010 list workflow with an impersonation step to replace the permissions for the current list item and I'm calling the 2010 workflow from the 2013 one.

Does anyone know how to get this to work?

If I start the workflow manually by right clicking the list item then it works as expected and updates the permissions. Conversely, if I add a test workflow which calls an impersonation step in a test 2010 workflow (but doesn't change any permissions) then this workflow works as expected as well.

So it looks like the permissions updating functionality works and the "workflow calling workflow" functionality works but I can't seem to get them both working at the same time

Is this even possible? Has anyone managed to get it working?

Many thanks

Tim

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like this does work.

I left it for a few days and then updated a list item to kick off the workflow. Permissions were updated as expected.

So for anyone else reading this, updating item permissions via workflow does work as an approach but you may have to patient when waiting for the updates to the workflow to take effect.